# How to filter rows from arrow::table based on a certain condition in Apache Arrow C++?

Tags: pyarrow, apache-arrow, apache-arrow-cpp

I want to do equivalent of pandas operation `df[df['certain_date'] > '2023-05-26']` . I have gone through almost all the Apache Arrow related answers on this site. I have been trying some combination of is_in compute function here - https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/compute.html but couldn't get it working. Is this even possible to do in C++? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible and there are a few ways you could go about it. One way is with the [Datasets API](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/dataset.html):

Assuming you're starting with an `arrow::Table` `tbl`, and are okay ending up with another `arrow::Table` with the result, `result`:

```cpp
// 1: Wrap the Table in a Dataset so we can use a Scanner
std::shared_ptr<arrow::dataset::Dataset> dataset =
    std::make_shared<arrow::dataset::InMemoryDataset>(tbl);

// 2: Build ScannerOptions for a Scanner to do a basic filter operation
auto options = std::make_shared<arrow::dataset::ScanOptions>();

options->filter = arrow::compute::greater(
    arrow::compute::field_ref("a"), 
    arrow::compute::literal(3)); // Change for your use case

// 3: Build the Scanner
auto builder = arrow::dataset::ScannerBuilder(dataset, options);
auto scanner = builder.Finish();

// 4: Perform the Scan and make a Table with the result
auto result = scanner.ValueUnsafe()->ToTable();
```

See https://gist.github.com/amoeba/32d93556560c3386c066b40f3d37d987 for a complete source listing.